# Need a sample Visual Studio 2012 iOS project for using Camera to scan a barcode

Tags: xamarin, zxing

I am very new to ZXing.
I need something very simple (I guess).
I use Visual Studio 2012, with an iPod.
I have opened a Xamarin project ('Hello World' project) in VS2012 (with the Xamarin plugin). now i need the onClick of a button to scan a barcode - which means to open the camera, and get a barcode.

I have downloaded the ZXing project [ZXing.Net.0.11.0.0.zip] but i dont know the following:
1. which project(s) should i include in my solution ?
2. which methods should i use ?

in other words - is there any ready sample project of this (in Visual Stuido, for iOS)?

another question, i have added to my solution 2 projects that Xamarin did for using the ZXing [ZXing.Net,  ZXing.Net.Mobile], they even has a ready test project for this:
https://github.com/Redth/ZXing.Net.Mobile
the problem is that the App loads on my iPod, but when i click on the button that should turn on the Camera to get a barcode, the screen gets black (just the App part, i still can see the top line on my iPod where the clock is), and the console in visual studio write 'starting to scan...' (or somthing like that. this is some debug output code to the Console that Xamarin did)

Anyone, please help me to solve this in some of these ways or both :)

Thanks,
Eyal

Comment: Please look at the answer for your post on zxing google groups: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/zxing/O5m20lBu7Zk